# How to convert a dataframe column object in python to date time format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format

How to convert a column value of object datatype in a dataframe to datetime format in python using pandas?

*Given below the sample value I get, when I execute `print(df['timestamp'])` for reference*

0          2020-02-03 18:00:33 
1          2020-02-03 18:00:37 
2          2020-02-03 18:00:39 
3          2020-02-03 18:01:16 
4          2020-02-03 18:01:17 
5          2020-02-03 18:02:14 
6          2020-02-03 18:02:46 
7          2020-02-03 18:02:50 
8          2020-02-03 18:02:58

### Please Note

- Data type of column timestamp is object

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['ColumnName'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ColumnName'])
```

Comment: Thanks @awfullycold it worked. I typed print(df['timestamp'].dtypes) and its showing datetime64[ns] format

Comment: Your welcome. Also you can check to access another example in documentation from here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html